# select from two SQL-fields issue

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL-query like:

```
SELECT tbl1.alloweduser, tbl2.ID, tbl2.user_login 
FROM tbl1, tbl2 
WHERE NOT tbl1.alloweduser <> tbl2.ID;
```

The query above compares two fields but outputs the fields that have the same value ("ID" and "alloweduser").

What I would like to do is to output the fields that's NOT matching from tbl2.

The **"ID"** has the values: 1,2,3,4,5 and the "**alloweduser**" has values of 1,2,3,4.

I would like to only output the value, **5** and it's corosponding user_login in this example.

How?

Comment: To do that you need to do a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT tbl2.user_login, tbl2.ID
FROM tbl2 
LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.alloweduser = tbl2.ID
WHERE tbl1.alloweduser IS NULL;
```

Comment: I think your JOIN order is wrong.  You need to do tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 since tbl2 contains the superset.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at using a LEFT JOIN with a null check for this:

```
SELECT tbl2.ID, tbl2.user_login
FROM tbl2
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl1
  ON tb2.ID = tb1.alloweduser
WHERE tbl1.alloweduser IS NULL
```

A great resource for figuring out how to specify joins is linked below:

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Note: For MySQL, you could simply specify `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as they are synonymous.

Comment: I like the link as example... check `tb2.alloweduser` --> `tb1.alloweduser`

Comment: @CharlesRojas Not clear about the last part of your comment.  The OP made no mention of a `tbl2.alloweduser` field.

Comment: @CharlesRojas Ah. I see. Thanks for catching the error. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem

```
WHERE NOT tbl1.alloweduser <> tbl2.ID;
```

**<>** means "not equals"

you are asking for

```
NOT a <> b
```

which is "NOT NOT equals"

you want

```
a <> b
```

OR

```
NOT a = b
```

NOT both.